# How to extract the tar.gz file but without overwriting existing files?

Tags: tar, zip, options

With the `unzip -n /path/to/filename/filename.zip` command the compressed file is uncompressed but does **not** overwrite existing files. This approach is useful when the same compressed file was uncompressed *before* and some files were either deleted or renamed - so with this `n` option they can retrieve them.

What is same approach for the `tar` command but for **extracting** purposes?

Normally I use the `tar -xzf  /path/to/filename.tar.gz` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options come to mind that should do what you want. From the [`tar` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar):

> `-k, --keep-old-files`
>
> don't replace existing files when extracting, treat them as errors

Alternatively:

> `--skip-old-files`
>
> don't replace existing files when extracting, silently skip over them